# Ag-grid drag and drop row to another grid

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there any way to drag a row to another grid and get row data of the destination grid?

I don't want to move or copy the row to the other grid. I need to connect source row to destination row and get ids of two rows.

Answer (score 0):

For drag and drop in ag-grid, you can take reference from here- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/drag-and-drop/#dragging-between-grids

It will be better if you can elaborate your use case a little bit more.
I will try to help you in this case.